# Wt Linking error on ubuntu

Tags: c++, ubuntu-16.04, wt

I installed WT:

```
sudo apt-get install witty witty-dbg witty-dev witty-doc
```

and now, when linking the Hello World example,

```
g++ -std=c++14 -o hello HelloW.cpp -I./src -L/usr/lib/lib -lwthttp -lwt
```

I get this error:

```
undefined reference to `Wt::Signals::Impl::Connection::~Connection()'
```

I wonder what I'm doing wrong. (Please look the odd link path I had to use).

**EDIT:**
I looked for one of the lib I'm trying to link:

```
find /usr/ -name "*wthttp*"

/usr/share/lintian/overrides/libwthttp38
/usr/share/lintian/overrides/libwthttp-dev
/usr/share/doc/libwthttp38
/usr/share/doc/libwthttp-dev
/usr/lib/libwthttp.so
/usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/libwthttp.so.3.3.4
/usr/lib/libwthttp.so.3.3.4
/usr/lib/libwthttp.so.38
/usr/lib/libwthttp.a
```

Comment: Obviously you are not linking the object file/library defining the symbol.

Comment: If you get linking errors during the first step, you might need to add more libraries: `g++ -std=c++14 -o hello hello.cc -I/usr/local/include -L/usr/local/lib -lwthttp -lwt -lboost_system -lboost_thread -lboost_filesystem -lboost_program_options`

Comment: @JesperJuhl I edited the question. Any suggestion? Thx

Comment: I expect you have a set of Wt header files that don't match the library maybe. maybe your header files are in /usr/include/Wt but you're linking against /usr/share/lintian/overrides/ or something like that ..

Comment: Try changing -L/usr/lib/lib to -L/usr/lib